Refresh the binding in a component for MAUI
In my .NET 8 MAUI project, I create a component like a ContentView. I pass to this component a property called Values.
Here is the definition:
public partial class EntryChoices : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ValuesProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Values), 
        typeof(List<string>), typeof(EntryChoices),
        null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public List<string>? Values
    {
        get => (List<string>)GetValue(ValuesProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValuesProperty, value);
    }
}

In the XAML, I use this value to bind a FlexLayout
<ContentView
    x:Name="cv">
    <VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference cv}" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <FlexLayout
            x:Name="FlexSkillContainer"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- More XAML -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>

If I add some values to the Values, this doesn't change the UI. I tried to add
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));

but this doesn't help nor add INotifyPropertyChanged to the ContentView. The function is as followed
public void AddItem(string item)
{
    if (Values == null)
        Values = new List<string>();

    Values.Add(item);
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Values));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueString));
}

I can't find a way to update the UI when the Values changed.
Update: now the Values is an ObservableCollection:
public static readonly BindableProperty ValuesProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Values), 
    typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(EntryChoices), 
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, 
    propertyChanged: OnValueChanged);

public ObservableCollection<string>? Values
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ValuesProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValuesProperty, value);
}

In the XAML, I call this view like
<components:EntryChoices
    x:Name="entryOriginal"
    Values="{Binding OriginalList}" />

The OriginalList is the view model is defined as
[ObservableProperty] 
private ObservableCollection<string> _originalList;

If I assign to this property a List with some values like
OriginalList = new ObservableCollection<string>(vl);

the component doesn't fire the set of the property Values.

Values should be an ObservableCollection, not a List

The UI should be changed though the Setter of BindableProperty does not fire. You don't need to put any extra logic in the set accessor. Instead, you may put the logic in the property-changed callback method,
private static void OnValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{

    var ec = bindable as EntryChoices;
    ec.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueString));
}  

For more info, you may refer to Detect property changes.

To me, this seems to be a binding issue.
Try adding Source={x:Reference cv} to your binding. Like this:
BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Source={x:Reference cv}}

